# useRef between components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have two components: `<Header/>` with hamburger button on it, and `<Sidebar/>`.

The idea is: if I click hamburger button the sidebar should be removed, or it should be appeared if I click back.

I have no issues to do so in one component where I use useRef:

```
  const sideBarRef = useRef()
  
  function toogleSideBar() {
    sideBarRef.current.classList.toggle('-translate-x-full')
  }
```

but I am not sure how to do it between components, where I have a layout with `<Header/>` and `<Sidebar/>` in it, and I need to initiate `toogleSidebar()` in `<Header/>` and some how pass `ref={sideBarRef}` in `<Sidebar/>`.

Answer (score 0):

As in most cases with React, there is no need to use a ref. A better approach is to lift the state up to the parent component and render the sidebar conditionally. The parent component is the one which renders both `Header` and `Sidebar`, let's call it `App`.

In your App component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(true);

  const toggleSidebar = () => setShowSidebar(prev => !prev);
  
  return (
    <main>
      <Header onClickMenu={toggleSidebar} />
      {showSidebar && <Sidebar />}
    </main>
  );
};
```

And then in your Header:

```
const Header = ({ onClickMenu }) => {  
  return (
    <nav>
      <Hamburger onClick={onClickMenu} />
      ...
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the state thru code like a variable

In App.js declare the

```
    //App.js
    let sideBarRef = useRef(false); 

    let content = (
        {sideBarRef? (<SideBar sideBarRef ={sideBarRef} />
                      ): null} 
        <Header sideBarRef ={sideBarRef} />
          


export default function SideBar({sideBarRef,}) {   
<use sideBarRef in code as if declare here>
}

export default function Header({sideBarRef,}) {   
<use sideBarRef as if declare here >
}
```

Comment: you may need to force a re-render, then set as useState the principle of passing state between the components is the same the state lives in app.js and is passed to other components,